# How to get index of first non zero value in a vector<int> in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the best way to do this.

For eg. I have

```
Vector<int> temp = {0,0,1,0,2}
```

I want to get the index of first non-zero value in the temp. So in this case I want answer 2.

I am already doing this, looking for a better way..

```
 int index = -1;
 for(int round=0; round < temp.size(); round++)
    {
       if(temp[round] > 0)
       {
           index = round;
           break;
       }
    }
```

Thanks,
Gunjan

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
distance( begin(temp), find_if( begin(temp), end(temp), [](auto x) { return x != 0; }));
```

This will return the size of the array if the item is not found. You will need `#include <algorithm>` and C++14 compilation mode.  In C++11 you must replace `auto` with `int` or whatever type your container contains.

---

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2954ec1b19356362) is a version with re-usable lambda, maybe slightly easier to read. Requires C++14.

Comment: NB. Depending on what you're planning to do with the result, it might be better to just save the iterator returned by `find_if` and work with that, instead of converting it to an index.

Comment: I am currently doing almost the same with for loop and returning value as soon as I found it. Is this better than what I am doing

Comment: depends how you define "better"

Comment: @Gunjan Isn't it clear by now why this code is better? Just look at what happened to my answer: You get a lot of downvotes if you dare to use a raw-loop in C++. It really hurts your reputation with some C++ folks. Silly me, I should have known better, it's not the first time I make this experience... Honestly, there are quite a few people who are very outspoken against raw loops (https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning), some of which are rather religious about it. It seems like some of them won't like you if you fail to use an STL-algorithm a single time you could.

Answer (score 2):

Like the first answer, just use `std::find_if_not` instead of `std::find_if`.

```cpp
bool IsZero(int i) {
    return i == 0;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> temp = {0, 0, 1, 0, 2};
    auto it = find_if_not(a.begin(), a.end(), IsZero);
    int first_nonzero_idx = distance(temp.begin(), it);

    return first_nonzero_idx;
}
```

Output is:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following function:

```
int FindSmallerIndex(const std::vector<int> & vec)
{
    int kMin=0;

    while(vec[kMin]==0)
    {
        kMin += 1;

    }

 return kMin;
}
```

Comment: This can read out of bounds if vec only contains zeros and also fails if vec is empty.

Answer (score 0):

More generic solution!

```
std::vector<int> a{0, 0, -1, 1, 0};
std::cout << std::distance(a.begin(),
                           std::find_if(a.begin(), a.end(),
                                        [](const auto& x) { return x; }))
          << '\n';
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is the obvious way:

```
int index = 0;
for(; index < temp.size(); index++) if(temp[index]) break;
if(index == temp.size()) {
    //no such element
} else {
    //first non-zero element is temp[index]
}
```

Any attempt to use stdlib-algorithms will just bloat your code.

Comment: In what way would using standard algorithms that everyone knows (or at least should know) "bloat your code" compared with writing your own code everywhere?

Comment: @erlc Just compare line 2 of my answer to M.M's answer. Mine is clearly shorter... Btw: Downvoters, please explain yourselves!

Comment: I myself feel, that it should be better than using algorithm. its doing the same thing and you dont have load the whole alogirthm class just for that. Correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: The discussion which is better heavily depends on two things. 
First: can you be completely sure your container will remain a vector? If you can't, then you'll have to refactor less if you use iterators to begin with. 
Second: The more compile time matters, the less you should use templates to replace what can be written using basic types - especially when you already know what types you'll use. 
Coding styles are different because priorities are.

Comment: @TinyT I don't know about you, but when I write C++ code, I only use these containers in order of frequency: `vector<>`, `unordered_map<>`, and `unordered_set<>`. All other containers would serve the same purposes, but offer worse performance. As such, I never replace a `vector<>` with another container, because there is no container that it's interchangeable with. It can't be replaced by an `unordered_map<>`, and it shouldn't be replaced by a `list<>`. That is why I won't bother making my code invariant to the type of container.

Comment: @cmaster valid choice. Typically I don't use iterators on containers which provide `operator[]` access, either. Still, with the requirement changes I've seen come and go, I wouldn't put it past the point for someone to do so.